# adding a grid with specific class in adaptivetheme

Tags: theming

I'm trying [omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) and [adaptivetheme](http://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme) to use responsive webdesign.
On omega that uses 960grid, I can add a "grid-X" class to an html element to display it in the grid, with the right width etc.
Is there a way to do the same thing with adaptivetheme?

Answer (score 1):

AT does not use Grid classes embedded in markup (it does not use grid classes at all).

If you are asking this I assume you do not really understand how this theme works - you use the layout system (in theme settings, for the main container/page and panels layouts) and write content/element specific CSS yourself, aka use a semantic grid approach.

Grid classes in markup are a huge limitation - what seems so easy now, turns quickly into a massive roadblock later on.

answer by author of adaptivetheme http://drupal.org/node/1861948